# Excluding files from jslint4java in eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jslint, jslint4java

I'm using jslint4java in eclipse. Unfortunately I have a few huge dictionary files that never change but every time when the workspace is built, linting those files takes ages.

Is it possible to exclude specific files from jslint4java and how can this be configured?

Comment: How are you running jslint4java?  Via ant, or maven?

Comment: It is running as an eclipse plugin. It can be installed from here: http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/jslint4java1/download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the version of the jslint4java Eclipse plug-in that I have (1.0.1.201207042009) there is an "Exclude files that match these patterns from JSLint:" field in the jslint4java preferences; I believe this is exactly what you are looking for.

It's below the "Make JSLint Laxer" list, on the right; if you have a long list of predefined global variables (as I do) you may have to scroll to see it.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter an exclusion pattern as mentioned above you need to disable and re-enable jslint on the project for it to take effect. Cost me an hour...

Answer (score -1):

Another note on excluding files using that pattern option. In my case I wanted to exclude every file that ended in .min.js. So, naturally I assumed the pattern would be *.min.js.

WRONG!

The pattern was just .min.js

Comment: This may be a useful tip but it does not answer the question and should be a comment to one of the real answers instead.